# Mismatch in the number of Class A requests for Google cloud storage between the bill and logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have enabled access and storage logs on the cloud storage buckets. I am loading the access logs generated to a BigQuery table for analysis. I see that the number of class A requests (mainly POST requests to create new objects in the bucket) reported by the logs is much more than the number of requests reported in the bill. Just to give an idea, for the month of December 2017 the logs report around 20 million requests but the bill reports only for around 5.5 million requests. 
I have ensured that the logs are not loaded more than once by de-duplicating on the `s_request_id` field.

From this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Default_Gcs_Bucket), it looks like only default bucket has free quota. But in my case, bucket is not the default one. 
I want to know if there are some requests which are not charged like free quota etc.

Comment: According to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free), you have 5k class A and 50 k class B operations free, per month. Taking into account [this calssification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) of operations, do you consider that out of the 20 mil requests, there are many `Free operations`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]: the answer was edited to summarize the discussion in its comments**

There are multiple operations considered free, as this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) states. Check
`Free Operations`.
Besides these free operations, there are "Always Free" usage limits [as well](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free).
This should answer your request,

> I want to know if there are some requests which are not charged like free quota etc.

But this does not explain why out of 20 mil logged requests, you have only 5.5 mil of them being billed.

OP's analysis led to the following:

> For each upload, 4 POST entries of operation `storage.objects.insert` show up in logs. Of these, 1 is POST to `/upload/storage/v1/b/` and 3 are POST to `/storage/v1/b/`. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload) says that former is for uploading media and latter for metadata. This checks out since `cs_bytes` is equal to file size for former and 0 for latter. I am using java client library to upload files from the client.
>
> *Should I consider entries with non 0 value in `cs_bytes` to calculate number of billable operations?*

---

In [the API reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/), more details on [insert](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) are available. It states

> Metadata-only requests are *not* allowed.

This means that a file needs to be uploaded for the `insert` to be valid. You can safely assume that each successful POST request to `/upload/storage/v1/b/` can be accounted for billing

Comment: The class A operation that I am referring to is POST request to create a new object in the cloud storage i.e. storage.objects.insert. This is not a free operation as per the first link that you have shared. I missed the "Always Free" usage limit, so thank you for that. But as per the link you have shared it is only 5000 class A operations per MONTH. So this wouldn't account for the difference

Comment: I will try and reproduce your situation and come back with a comment after that. Until then, I was able to run `$ gsutil logging set on -b gs://bucket_storing_own_logs_maybe gs://bucket_storing_own_logs_maybe`. This means that the same bucket that is being logged is also the one that is storing logs. Can this be your case? Log creation operations (we can consider them class A requests, right?) will not be billed. This is plausible...

Comment: In my case, logs are stored in a different bucket. So I don't think this is the case. But even if this was the case, it would still not explain the difference. Because in my case there are around 30 buckets. So the number of files created for a month would be 30 buckets * (24 usage logs + 1 storage logs) * 30days. I also confirmed that I count only the operations which were successful. Because this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) says that `Generally, you are not charged for operations that return 307, 4xx, or 5xx responses.`

Comment: Do the daily operations logged in the App Engine usage history of your project reflect the 5.5 mil billed or the 20 mil logged?
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails/history

Comment: The daily usage csv report actually has 0 for "Used", "Billable" and "Charge" columns. I think [audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs) has to be enabled for Cloud Storage for storage statistics to be reflected in the usage history. I have enabled this now. I'll have to wait for a couple of days to check this. Meanwhile please do share any other angles that you can think of. Thank you for your continued interest in helping me to solve this. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm with Google Cloud Platform Support. Share your feedback regarding your last check. If it is not fruitful, I suggest opening a [technical support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/#contacting_technical_support) within GCP or file an issue in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). Share the case number/issue number here so that I can handle it internally. Of course, if possible, we'll return with the correct answer for the community.

Comment: Also support here. Filing a "private" issue on our issue tracker would be the best way to get us any information you don't feel like you can share on here. The Direct link to do that is [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901)

Comment: Did some more analysis:
For each upload, 4 POST entries of operation `storage.objects.insert` show up in logs. Of these, 1 is POST to `/upload/storage/v1/b/` and 3 are POST to `/storage/v1/b/`. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload) says that former is for uploading media and latter for metadata. This checks out since `cs_bytes` is equal to file size for former and 0 for latter.
I am using java client library to upload files from the client.
Should I consider entries with non 0 value in `cs_bytes` to calculate number of billable operations?

Comment: In the [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) more details on [insert](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) are available. It states `Metadata-only requests are _not_ allowed`. This means that a file needs to be uploaded for the `insert` to be valid. You can safely assume that each successful `POST` request to `/upload/storage/v1/b/` can be accounted for billing